# Where can I set the Eclipse C++ Function Name Style?

Tags: c++, eclipse, naming-conventions, eclipse-indigo, codan

The Codan analysis for naming conventions is giving me "Bad function name" info messages beause it expects camelCase and I use CamelCase. (I know I can turn this off but I would rather have it enforce my naming conventions).

I'm using Eclipse/CDT Indigo. Under the Windows->Preferences there is a C/C++->Code Style->Name Style (see image), but under Code it doesn't have an option for Method names. This is strange since it has a more specific entry for Getter and Setter methods.  Where is Codan getting the style it's using for validation?

[image: screen shot of prefs dialog]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click on info message in the Problems window, and select the `Customize Problem...` option at the bottom of the context menu:

[image]

and change the pattern for function naming to `^[A-Z]`

[image]